# Android unit tests how to run a method only once

Tags: android, junit, crashlytics

I have subclass of Application  called myApplication, and i have a method in there to setup crashlytics.  But in my unit tests everytime i run a test its restarting a new Application so then it tries to setup crashlytics again each time and then eventually i just get Out of memory exception.  How can i force a method to only be executed once since its in Application which is the foundation of the application.

my subclass if necessary , looks like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
setupCrashlytics();
}


/**
 * sets up Crashlytics.
 */
private void setupCrashlytics() {

        Crashlytics.Builder crashlytics= new Crashlytics.Builder();
        Fabric.Builder fabric= new Fabric.Builder(this);


        fabricBuilder.kits(crashlytics.build());
        Fabric.with(fabric.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're running instrumentation tests, which are dependent of the configuration you apply in your Application subclass.
Although the tests should be run in an environment as close as possible to the production, you can differentiate your test environment by exposing a `MyApplication.setIsTestEnvironment()` method and using the flag to enable/disable third party dependencies when you're testing.

Alternatively, some testing libraries (i.e. *Mockito*) allow you to fully or partially mock an object. You can do that to prevent your real Application class from initializing unwanted dependencies when testing.

Comment: this is exactly what i end up doing. it just seems a little ugly but thanks